# How to increase consumer object dynamically in spring amqp (rabbitmq)

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

i have a Sender class that sends the message to a queue and a Receiver class with a method to receive the messages , its working fine . if i send 10 message to queue , these are successfully consumed by Receiver . 
Now the problem is if i send 1000 of message then single receiver instance(object) 
takes more time to process 1000 message ,then i create the two instance of receiver to process fast. it is also working fine but i want to increase this receiver object dynamically , like if my queue have more than 1000 message then dynamically , one more instance(object) of receiver class should be created .
like work queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`? If so, you can set `concurrentConsumers` and `maxConcurrentConsumers` and they will increase as needed based on some configuration options.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#listener-concurrency).

Comment: thanq very much , i got what i want

Comment: I see you are new here - it is customary to "accept" an answer - it will help others - just click the tick/check mark below the voting buttons on the left.